# reactjs apollo react cancel request

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have an issue whereby you navigate to a page and apollo retrieves the data. While apollo is doing that and you navigate to another page, the apollo does not cancel the request and throws the following error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application
```

Is there any way to cancel or abort the request from `ComponentDidUnmount`?

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.client.query({ ... })
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    // cancel or abort query here
}
```

Thanks!